# SQL Error - The multi-part identifier "CF.OBJ" could not be bound

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Im getting an error on multi part identifier for Sub query join. Please help. Following is the code I have written

```
SELECT CORE.BC_NUMBER AS BC,SEG.BC_NUMBER AS SEGBC,XREF.BC_NUMBER AS XREFBC,CF.OBJ
-- Table CORE
From CORE

-- join seg and core
LEFT JOIN SEG
ON CORE.BC_NUMBER= SEG.BC_NUMBER

-- Join XREF to go from BCNbr to GBC
LEFT JOIN 
XREF
ON XREF.BUNL=SEG.BC_NUMBER;

-- GEN JOIN GBC
LEFT JOIN

(SELect JID,P,Obj, JT
From Gen) AS CF

ON CF.Obj=XREF.BC_NUMBER

;
```

sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29f643/15

Comment: change `From Gen AS CF) ON....` to `From Gen) AS CF ON ....` on the last left join

Comment: You may want to spell out the word `SELECT` in that last `LEFT JOIN` as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the alias inside the sub-query; try the following:

```
SELECT CORE.BC_NUMBER AS BC,SEG.BC_NUMBER AS SEGBC,XREF.BC_NUMBER AS 

XREFBC,CF.OBJ
-- Table CORE
From CORE

-- join seg and core
LEFT JOIN SEG
ON CORE.BC_NUMBER= SEG.BC_NUMBER

-- Join XREF to go from BCNbr to GBC
LEFT JOIN XREF
ON XREF.BUNL=SEG.BC_NUMBER

-- GEN JOIN GBC
LEFT JOIN (   
    SELECT JID,P,Obj, JT
    From Gen
    where JT=28 and P=1
)CF
ON CF.Obj=XREF.BC_NUMBER
;
```

Comment: On the second `LEFT JOIN` remove the `;` semicolon. That is stopping the 3rd `LEFT JOIN` from being seen by SQL.

Answer (score 0):

As you have used CF alias inside the parentheses and taking reference outside of it. Here CF alias is not created yet, please use CF alias outside the parentheses to use it as a reference

```
SELECT CORE.BC_NUMBER AS BC,SEG.BC_NUMBER AS SEGBC,XREF.BC_NUMBER AS XREFBC,CF.OBJ
-- Table CORE
From CORE

-- join seg and core
LEFT JOIN SEG
ON CORE.BC_NUMBER= SEG.BC_NUMBER

-- Join XREF to go from BCNbr to GBC
LEFT JOIN 
XREF
ON XREF.BUNL=SEG.BC_NUMBER;

-- GEN JOIN GBC
LEFT JOIN

(SEL JID,P,Obj, JT
From Gen 
) AS CF
ON CF.Obj=XREF.BC_NUMBER
;
```